# How do I find which eventargs class to use in asp.net control event

Tags: asp.net, eventargs

If I add an event to my control in the markup, eg in and EntityDataSource add a OnUpdating,
how can I find the method parameter list?

eg how do I know to put in

```
(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs e)
```

instead of

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In a FormView OnDataBinding event is there a more specific EventArgs class than

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is defined by the `event` signature. Not much you can, but rewrite the code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I would just type in EntityDataSource OnUpdating into google....almost always within the first few results I'll see an example with the correct parameter list.